# Can getID3 get data of mp3 file that is input for FFT?

Tags: php, fft, getid3

I want to compare two pieces of music to find similarities. But actually, I don't understand what Fast Fourier Transform is. I don't even know the parameter of the FFT function(from https://gist.github.com/mbijon/1332348).

My questions are:

1. What are the parameters to FFT function?
2. Does getID3 function provide these parameters?
3. If not, how can I get these paramaters?

Here is my code.

```
<?php
    require_once('assets/getID3/getid3/getid3.php');
    require_once('FFT.php');
    $getID3 = new getID3;
    $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze("music.mp3");
    $bit_rate = $ThisFileInfo['audio']['bitrate'];
    var_dump($bit_rate);
?>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thank you for comment @Kmeixner. i already saw this wiki, but it makes me crazy...

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. I had an entire university engineering course dedicated to using FFT. It was long ago, I don't remember much, but it was a way to measure the frequency of waveforms such as soundwaves. This one's a little easier to understand: http://www.askamathematician.com/2012/09/q-what-is-a-fourier-transform-what-is-it-used-for/

Comment: The input to the FFT function in question is the audio data from your song (i.e the actual audio samples), and for the $sign parameter all you need to put is "1" because you want to perform a forward Fourier transform.I don't know if ID3 can provide you with that data because I am not familiar with getID3 and php.

Comment: I'm really appreciate @Kmeixner's and KillaKem's comment!

Comment: @KillaKem you mean, input parameter is a file?

Comment: No not the file but the actual data samples.A song contains a lot of metadata such as Artist Name, BitRate e.t.c and it also contains the actual audio song.You need to find some way of extracting the audio samples (these will be an array of numbers between -1 and 1) and then spacing that array with zeros before inputting them as an argument to the FFT function.